# How to fix "ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for FileBasedMavenArtifact_Decorated aar"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to build my lib with aar file. After upgrading to the latest android gradle plugin 3.4.2 I am getting this error: ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for FileBasedMavenArtifact_Decorated aar:null of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.artifact.FileBasedMavenArtifact.
How to fix that one inside publishing section?

I have tried changing 
    builtBy assembleRelease
into
    builtBy 'assembleRelease'
but in that case I loose assembleRelease from my tasks in gradle.

```
    publications {
        Production(MavenPublication) {
        artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${archivesBaseName}-       {$versions.versionName}.aar") {
                builtBy assembleRelease
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
builtBy tasks.getByName('assembleRelease')
```

and this is work for me